# Give specific cars of a breed their own instructions Netlogo

Tags: jsp

Okay I have been re modelling the for a while now to demonstrate what smart cars would behave like on a real world motorway. I have a slider that changes the colour of half the cars on the road and I would like to have these cars have their own settings and the other cars to behave the same. Here is the code that changes the colour.

This is the setup procedure and the variables for the car breed.

```
cars-own [


If after I run the go procedure and I wanted the specific cars that have their colours changed to go around the road differently either based on the cars speed or the drivers patience to switch lane how do I specifically identify them?

I tried an If statement where I say if the car's colour isn't orange red or yellow do .....
but that doesn't work.
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: If you want this post to be deleted, you can either flag it for moderator attention, explaining why, or contact a member of staff through the "Contact us" link at the bottom of every page.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to define another breed of car and then have those cars that have changed color also change their breed. You can then refer to all such cars by their new breed name.  E.g.,

```
breed [cars2 car2]
cars2-own [
the same variables as cars-own
]
....
to set-level-of-autonomy
  let num-change number-of-cars / 2 - count turtles with [color = orange or color = red or color = yellow]
  ask n-of num-change cars
  [ if level-of-autonomy = 0 [set color blue set breed cars2]
    if level-of-autonomy = 1 [set color blue + 1.0 set breed cars2]
    if level-of-autonomy = 2 [set color cyan set breed cars2]
    if level-of-autonomy = 3 [set color turquoise set breed cars2]
    if level-of-autonomy = 4 [set color green set breed cars2]
    if level-of-autonomy = 5 [set color lime set breed cars2]
  ]
end
```

When `cars` change their `breed` to `cars2`, the values of their "own" variables will remain unchanged as long as these variables have been listed as `cars2-own` variables as well. You can now refer to cars and cars2 separately. Note, that if all cars have one of the five specified values of level-of-autonomy, you can simplify a bit.

```
to set-level-of-autonomy
      let num-change number-of-cars / 2 - count turtles with [color = orange or color = red or color = yellow]
      ask n-of num-change cars
      [ if level-of-autonomy = 0 [set color blue]
        if level-of-autonomy = 1 [set color blue + 1.0]
        if level-of-autonomy = 2 [set color cyan]
        if level-of-autonomy = 3 [set color turquoise]
        if level-of-autonomy = 4 [set color green]
        if level-of-autonomy = 5 [set color lime set]
        set breed cars2
      ]
    end
```

Another approach would be to define an agentset of cars with changed colors rather than a new breed.

```
globals [changed-cars]
......
let changed-cars no-turtles
........
    to set-level-of-autonomy
          let num-change number-of-cars / 2 - count turtles with [color = orange or color = red or color = yellow]
          ask n-of num-change cars
          [ if level-of-autonomy = 0 [set color blue]
            if level-of-autonomy = 1 [set color blue + 1.0]
            if level-of-autonomy = 2 [set color cyan]
            if level-of-autonomy = 3 [set color turquoise]
            if level-of-autonomy = 4 [set color green]
            if level-of-autonomy = 5 [set color lime set]
            set changed-cars (turtle-set changed-cars self)
          ]
        end
```

Each changed car puts itself in the agentset `changed-cars`.  Now, `cars` refers to all cars while `changed-cars` refers to only those cars that have changed. `changed-cars` is a subset of `cars`. With `breeds`, the two breeds are independent of each other.